# XML-(de)serialize list property of integers as a simple delimiter-separated sequence

Tags: c#, xml

I am operating on an (externally given) XML file with elements of the form

```
<SomeElement SomeAttribute1 = "10" SomeAttribute2 = "Bla">
    10 20 30 40
    50 60 70 80
</SomeElement>
```

I know how to deal with the attributes as properties (by using `[XmlAttribute]`) but I don't know how to easily get the whitespace-separated values in the content body into a `List<int>`.

Of course I can just treat the content as a string attribute and do the parsing for myself (by creating a separate `[XmlIgnore]` property of type `List<int>`).

But it would be nicer if there was a C#-attribute that instructs the (de)serializer to do that automatically, like (pseudo-code)

```
public class
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int SomeAttribute1 {get; set;}

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int SomeAttribute2 {get; set;}

    [XmlParseListAsDelimitedSequence(" ")]
    public List<int> Values {get; set;}
}
```

Is there any?

Comment: Your expectation that a (de)serializer will make up for bad XML design is unfounded.

Comment: @kjhughes: Don't blame me, I am just trying to work with what I have... So may I interpret your words as a synonym for "no"?

Comment: BTW: why is it bad XML design at all? Then setting the text of a WPF button in XAML would be bad design also...

Comment: Why do you think the `XmlSerializer` is able to handle such an arbirary format? Of course yiu have to do this yourself. Obviously it´s not that hard using `String.Split()`, is it?

Comment: To be fair to OP, if this were JSON, it would be fairly trivial to handle this, is it such a stretch to hope that XML serialisation would also be possible?

Comment: @HimBromBeere: I have not problem with doing this myself if it isn't available out of the box, but I would hesitate if it meant reinventing the wheel. And how should I know that this is an arbitrary format for XML, when I find it in an output of a commercial software. I am not an XML expert, otherwise I wouldn't need to ask...

Comment: It's bad XML design because it has data with constituent parts that are not elements or attributes, thus requiring microparsing.  To expect that you can *avoid* microparsing data within poorly designed XML is unreasonable.

Comment: Provided current structure could be possible with writing a custom deserialization process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest option is to serialise to text and parse the value manually later. You could do this:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("SomeElement")]
public class Foo
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int SomeAttribute1 { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int SomeAttribute2 { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Raw { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<int> Values => Raw
        .Split(new [] {" ", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(int.Parse)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you David. I'll accept it after a little more waiting if a second opinion turns up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XamlServices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xaml.xamlservices(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead of `XmlSerializer` to get a compact collection save automatically.

You will also have to use [Int32Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.int32collection(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `List<int>`.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int SomeAttribute1 { get; set; }
    public int SomeAttribute2 { get; set; }
    public Int32Collection Values { get; set; }
}
```

Note that although the int properties are not marked `XmlAttribute`, they are still stored as an xml attribute.

```
var foo = new Foo
{
    SomeAttribute1 = 1,
    SomeAttribute2 = 2,
    Values = new Int32Collection(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 })
};

Console.WriteLine(XamlServices.Save(foo));
```

Result:

```
<Foo SomeAttribute1="1" SomeAttribute2="2" Values="1 2 3" xmlns="clr-namespace:ConApp1;assembly=ConApp1" />
```

Comment: Wow, that's really interesting. But I wonder if this is actually intended to be used by the average XML user. If not and I switch to it, could I get into a dead end on some otherwise common XML features?

Comment: @oliver - It's part of WPF. This way you get attached to this platform. In dead end you will get, if want to switch on .NET Core, etc.

Comment: I doubt this will help OP much, as "I am operating on an (externally given) XML file". Your xml is quite different from the OPs one.